# javascript setter injection without eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, prototype

I'm trying to use a setter injection in this example below, it works but I cannot yet find out how to achieve the same result without using eval().

```
var action = function(){};

action.prototype.create = function(type, name) {
   var action = eval("this."+type);
   action.create(name);
};

action.prototype.review = {
    create: function(name){
        console.log("hey "+name);
    }
};

var bang = new action();
bang.create('review','john');
```

I'm running this on nodejs v0.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get javascript object property via key name in variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556673/get-javascript-object-property-via-key-name-in-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that context, `eval("this."+type)` should be equivalent to `this[type]`.

Here's a [JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/lucacufububo/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: There are probably hundreds of dup questions/answers to this common issue.

Comment: It is also safer as IE8 won't freak of for reserved keywords like for, while, class etc.