# Check the variable's value is the Javascript object array's key and return that key's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
array = {
event: [{
        key: "value",
        lbl: "value"
    }],
event1: [{
        key: "value",
        lbl: "value"
    }]

var variable;
if(variable in array){
//what to do here?
}
```

I have a value in the variable which will be the name of the array inside the array (i.e):variable="event" or "event1";
i want a function to return the array with the key in the variable!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name) and [How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875) and [Get javascript object property via key name in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]`  [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object if you want to access any property using variable

```js
let arr = {event: [{key: "value",lbl: "value"}],event1: [{key: "value",lbl: "value"}]}

var variable = 'event1'

console.log(arr[variable])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bracket notation to access the key from the object

```js
array = {
event: [{
        key: "value",
        lbl: "value"
    }],
event1: [{
        key: "value",
        lbl: "value"
    }]
}
var variable='event1';
console.log(variable, array[variable])
```

Comment: Missing explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` variable isn't an array, its an object. You can access an object's properties/values (ie: `event` and `event1`) using bracket notation:

```
arr["event1"] // returns the array (the key's value) at event one.
```

Thus, you can use the following arrow function to get any value from any given `key` from any given `obj`ect:

```
getVal = (obj, key) => obj[key];
```

While a function isn't necessary, I have created one as per your request. Alternatively, you can just use:

```
obj[varaible] // returns the array (value) from the key (variable)
```

See working example below:

```js
const obj = {
  event: [{
    key: "value",
    lbl: "value"
  }],
  event1: [{
    key: "value",
    lbl: "value"
  }]
},
getVal = (obj, key) => obj[key],

variable = "event";
console.log(getVal(obj, variable));
```