# How can you retrieve a specific key in a object using the keyname?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to get the object key name using the value. Is it possible?

I have tried using Object.keys and can't imagine looping working successfully.

```
for (var x in inspections) {
    if (inspections[x] == "NA") {
         //Somehow get inspections key at inspections value`
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the answer you posted?

Comment: If the `==` test succeeds then you know the key is the current value of `x`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get javascript object property via key name in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556673/get-javascript-object-property-via-key-name-in-variable)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't targeting IE11 you can use Object.entries, for IE11 you can create a shim fairly easily.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

For your case:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(inspections)) {
  if (value === 'NA'){
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getKey = (obj, val) => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).find(key => obj[key] === val);

const obj = { prop1: 'test1', prop2: 'test2' };

console.log(getKey(obj, 'test2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inspections = { "1": "NA", "2": "A" }

for (let x in inspections) {
  if (inspections[x] == "NA") {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

The answer you posted is actually correct. When you find a match in the if statement, the `x` is the key you want. If you want to get the key, just do:

```js
const inspections = { "1": "NA", "2": "A" }

let key = null;

for (let x in inspections) {
  if (inspections[x] == "NA") {
    key = x;
    break;
  }
}

if (key !== null) {
    // we found a key, do something with it
    console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you. Been struggling on this for a while and guess I lost my brain.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the first key found for the value passed in.

[image]